# Wordpress 4.7.x Installer issue

Tags: wordpress, installation

After activating the CiviCRM plugin within Wordpress and opening the 'CiviCRM Installer' I am unable to alter the CiviCRM Database settings fields to point to my CiviCRM database.

The fields are pre-populated with my Wordpress database details and whenever I alter them and press 'Re-check requirememnts' my details are removed and the Wordpress database details re-appear.

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- IIS 8
- php 5.4.45
- MySQL 5.1.73
- Wordpress 4.4.1

The installer for 4.6.x works fine, after upgrading to 4.7.x, the upgrade is successful but I receive Datatables warnings on fields with Tab with table Display styles (such as Relationships) and wanted to try a fresh install.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour before, or able to help me resolve this?

Many thanks
Russell

Comment: Please provide some screen shots if possible - that will be more helpful

Comment: Thanks Christian. While this does seem to complete the install and populate the correct database with tables, the CiviCRM menu bar does not display. I have tried to rebuild the menu using the url:
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?age=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1 but this makes not difference. Am I missing something else here? I had no such problems with 4.6.x

Comment: Have you tried CiviCRM Admin Utilities? https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/

Comment: I meant to add that it will fix the rendering of the CiviCRM menu. There are also options to clear other CiviCRM caches that you can use. Hopefully the combination will bring your menu back.

Comment: @Russell, the StackExchange format is different than a discussion forum. Your response should be either a comment or (when you have the points required) an edit to your original question.

Comment: @ChristianWach Thanks for the advice.  I have now tried the Admin Utilities and this was also unable to fix the missing menu.  I also tried the other options as well as clearing cache - no positive result.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3322)

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this behaviour too. Just make sure your database details are correctly entered, then use the "Check Requirements and Install CiviCRM" button above the details instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in the installer for 4.7.   I created https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19279  to track the issue.   With Christian's help I created a PR - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9029  I have tested this locally and on one of our test sites and it works.

I'd appreciate any testing that can be done with this to make it a merge candidate.

Comment: Hi, I am having exactly the same problem  I apologise in advance for my naivety here - but how do we access a patch/fix for this?

Comment: You can wait until version 4.7.12 or if you know how to apply a patch, this PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9029/files has the change.  -- Basically a few lines were inserted that should have been there from the start - line 121 is where is starts.  The patch is "bigger" as there were some code formatting changes done as well.